# ¿Cual es el nombre de la variable en esta consulta?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
select sum(monto) as total_ingreso, date(fecha_creacion) 
from movimientos 
where date(fecha_creacion) between "2019-06-04" and "2019-06-05" 
      and tipo_movimiento=1 group by date (fecha_creacion);
```

Con el siguiente resultado.

```
total_ingreso  date(fecha_creacion)
   11300           2019-06-04          
   12800           2019-06-05
```

Lo utilizo dentro de un forech para el valor "total_ingreso".

```
foreach ($egresos as $egreso) {
echo "$egreso->total_ingreso";
}
```

La pregunta es para el valor "date(fecha_creacion)" como seria el forech, ya intente.

```
echo "$egreso->date(fecha_creacion)";
```

y

```
echo "$egreso->date_fecha_creacion";
```

Comment: lo mismo que hiciste con el `count` de colocarle un alias para poderlo recuperar después, lo mismo has con la fecha formateada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Del mismo modo que para la función de agregación `count()` le diste un alias de este modo:

```
sum(monto) as total_ingreso
```

El cual te sirve para recuperarlo como el nombre de la columna resultante, de ese mismo modo deberás hacerlo para el caso de la fecha que formateas por medio de la función `date()`; quedando así:

```
date(fecha_creacion) as Fecha
```

Dicho lo anterior, ya dentro de tu bucle *foreach* podrás recuperar ambos por dichos alias que les fueron asignados.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya puedo manejar la infomacion de esa campo. Saludos.